# Suggestion needed writing a complex query - sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have 4 columns in a table called musics - `'artist','genre', 'writer' , 'producer'.`

I need to write a query such that, it returns a value 0 , if there are no repetition of values corresponding to the column name; if there is a repetition of values, it should return a value 1, corresponding to that column name.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: just add query that you tried

Comment: which value?? **`'artist'or 'genre'or 'writer' or 'producer'.`**

Comment: corresponding to all those - 'artist','genre', 'writer' and 'producer'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT (COUNT(artist)   <> COUNT(DISTINCT artist))   artist,
       (COUNT(genre)    <> COUNT(DISTINCT genre))    genre,
       (COUNT(writer)   <> COUNT(DISTINCT writer))   writer,
       (COUNT(producer) <> COUNT(DISTINCT producer)) producer
FROM musics
```

Another version

```
SELECT 
( SELECT (COUNT(*) > 0) 
    FROM (SELECT 1 FROM musics GROUP BY artist HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) a 
) artist,
( SELECT (COUNT(*) > 0) 
    FROM (SELECT 1 FROM musics GROUP BY genre HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) g 
) genre,
( SELECT (COUNT(*) > 0) 
    FROM (SELECT 1 FROM musics GROUP BY writer HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) w 
) writer,
( SELECT (COUNT(*) > 0) 
    FROM (SELECT 1 FROM musics GROUP BY producer HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) p 
) producer
```

Sample data

```
|  artist |  genre |  writer |  producer |
------------------------------------------
| artist1 | genre1 | writer1 | producer1 |
| artist2 | genre2 | writer1 | producer2 |
| artist1 | genre3 | writer3 | producer3 |
```

Sample output:

```
| artist | genre | writer | producer |
--------------------------------------
|      1 |     0 |      1 |        0 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9a3d8/10)**

Comment: brilliant. bang on! Though I get the 1 and 0 toggled in the result - ie; I get 0 in place of 1 and 1 in place of 0

Comment: @user264953 It does exactly as you asked 0 - if there is no repetition, 1 - if there is one

Answer (score 2):

For **`Artist`**

```
select convert(bit,(count(1)-1))
from table_name
group by artist  -- <-- Replace artist with column name for which duplicate
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake . Actually I needed this for sqlite and the query is not working for sqlite. Also, can I get  'artist','genre', 'writer' and 'producer' using a single query?

Answer (score 1):

write a select count statement using distinct with specified column and another select count without distinct and compare both of them based on your requirement

Answer (score 1):

you can use 4 different query with union & each query must contain count(column name) + group by clause